# Cross checking if value in column 1 is X, value in column 2 should be Y

Tags: mysql

So I got 2 columns whereby they have different values but are dependent. I want to find those that are not showing the correct values. I really am stumped about what to do.

```
SELECT *
```

Let's take those value ends with html should have a value of 3 in the answer column,py should have a value of 4 in the answer column, jpg should have a value of 5 in the answer column and Null should reflect Null in the answer column

| webpage | answer |
| --- | --- |
| abc.html | 3 |
| xyz.py | 4 |
| qrs.html | 2 |
| syt.jpg | 5 |
| NULL | 1 |

Result should show

| webpage | answer |
| --- | --- |
| qrs.html | 2 |
| NULL | 1 |

Comment: Sorry I have been spending 10mins and formatting seems to be an issue which I for the life of me unsure why it is causing so much issue when i follow the same format as my previous qns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` to check for all those possible combinations. For example:

```
select t.*,
  case
    when webpage like '%.html' then
      case when answer = 3 then 'VALID' else 'INVALID' end
    when webpage like '%.py' then
      case when answer = 4 then 'VALID' else 'INVALID' end
    when webpage like '%.jpg' then
      case when answer = 5 then 'VALID' else 'INVALID' end
    when webpage is null then
      case when answer is null then 'VALID' else 'INVALID' end
    else 'Unrecognized webpage'
  end as validation
from t
```

**EDIT**:

If you only want to show the invalid ones then you can do:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    case
      when webpage like '%.html' then
        case when answer = 3 then 'VALID' else 'INVALID' end
      when webpage like '%.py' then
        case when answer = 4 then 'VALID' else 'INVALID' end
      when webpage like '%.jpg' then
        case when answer = 5 then 'VALID' else 'INVALID' end
      when webpage is null then
        case when answer is null then 'VALID' else 'INVALID' end
      else 'Unrecognized webpage'
    end as validation
  from t
) x
where validation <> 'VALID'
```

Comment: Thank you and will definitely try this. Very sorry my formatting really giving me an issue everytime I correct it and now it only accept as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  your_table
WHERE
     (webpage LIKE '%.html' AND answer <> 3)
  OR (webpage LIKE '%.py'   AND answer <> 4)
  OR (webpage LIKE '%.jpg'  AND answer <> 5)
  OR (webpage IS NULL       AND answer IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This works thanks but having the else statement would be the most ideal after trying all the methods here.

Comment: @JoseJondoe For what purpose? Please add whatever you need that for to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `CASE` to check in `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM test
   WHERE CASE WHEN webpage LIKE '%html' AND answer=3 THEN 1
              WHEN webpage LIKE '%py' AND answer=4 THEN 1
              WHEN webpage LIKE '%jpg' AND answer=5 THEN 1
              WHEN webpage IS NULL AND answer IS NULL THEN 1
           ELSE 0 END = 0
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab9199782d6a135918268b8cb46fce4a)

Comment: Thank you! and also thank you for helping me showcase the question correctly!